# EF6 Many to Many Delete Not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have two models [DOCTOR] & [CONTACTS] that are associated via a many-to-many relationship using Entityframework 6.0. I can add a doctor find with the following:

DM is a wrapper class around the doctor entity so that I can bind to it using onpropertychange.

```
using (var context = new RxStoreEntities())
{
   contact C = context.contacts.First(i => i.LoginID == loginID);
   C.Doctors1.Add(DM.DOCTOR);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I do the following to try to delete it, it will not delete. I even checked SQL Profiler and I am not seeing the delete SQL function like I should be seeing. The code for the delete is as follows:

```
using (var context = new RxStoreEntities())
{
      contact C = context.contacts.First(i => i.LoginID == loginID);
      C.Doctors1.Remove(DM.DOCTOR);
      context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DM.DOCTOR isn't tracked by your context. Before SaveChanges, call:

```
context.Doctors.Attach(DM.DOCTOR);
```